# Collections.sort not give expected

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort the index of an array based on the value at that index. Eg. [0,2,2,1] would give [0,2,3,1] or [0,3,2,1]

```
List<Integer> index_map = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3));
final int[] sizes = {0,2,1,1};

Collections.sort(index_map, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return sizes[a] < sizes[b] ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sizes));
System.out.println(index_map);
```

However, using Collections.sort() and the defined comparartor gives [0,3,1,2] instead. Can someone tell me why the output is like that and if there's a better way to accomplish the target? Thanks

Comment: It's usually unnecessary to write your own `compare` method; use something like `Comparator.comparingInt(i -> sizes[i])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FIX:** you miss th case for equal value and don't re-implement the comparison code, use the method `Integer.compare` directly :

```
List<Integer> index_map = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3));
final int[] sizes = {0,2,1,1};

Collections.sort(index_map, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Integer.compare(sizes[a],sizes[b]);
    }
});
```

**Improve:** it can be reduce with it's lambda version

```
Collections.sort(index_map, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(sizes[a], sizes[b]));
```

**Best:** use the comparingInt that allows to just specify the value to use to compare, also you can direcrly call `sort` on the list :

```
index_map.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> sizes[a]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But this is what I got using the "Best" solution. sizes=[0,2,2,1] and output index_map=[0,3,1,2]

Comment: @ThompsonLiu This is normal, it starts with 0, then 3, then 1 and 2 have same size (which is 2) so between them there is no order, so 0,3,1,2 is OK and could be 0,3,2,1 too

Comment: can someone please explain what is happening. how are they getting compared?

Comment: @prashant.kr.mod for each value of `index_map` you take their corresponding value in `sizes` : value `0` => value `0` at index `0` // value `1` => value `2` at index `1` // value `2` => value `1` at index `2` // value `3` => value `1` at index `3`